# replace matrix element python 3.4.3

Tags: python, matrix, replace

I need to replace an element of a matrix.
I initiate a 4x4 matrix through the command `M=4*[4*[0]]`.

For example I want to change the `(0,1)` element.

For logic I write:

`M[0,1]=1`

and the error code says

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

So I try:

`M[0][1]=1`

but instead of change only the `(0,1)` element, it changes all the "second column" in this way:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

What's the problem? How can I replace only one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you do something like this:

```
M=4*[4*[0]]
```

You are not creating different lists, you are simply copying a reference to the same list four times. So if you make a change in one of your sublists with your methodology of creating that 4x4 matrix, you are seeing the expected behaviour.

Official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x) will explain this further as well

You should do something like this to achieve what you are looking for:

```
[[0 for x in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
```

Now, you have four different lists in your list. If you make a change it will only be with reference to that explicit index you provide.

Answer (score 0):

create the Array like this:

```
M = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

then `M[0][1] = 1` will work